# Inhert model in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have to models that are practically the same, just diferent table in db and a new field,
So is there a way in zend framework so I can inhert from the first class? and just change these two things?

The same for the controlles and view.

Comment: Please see [PHP Object inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php), zend framework itself makes use of this, too. So you have got a real live example directly on your computer system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extends those classes like any other php class by using the "extend" call.

```
class Application_Model_Foo extends Application_Model_Bar
```

the same goes for controllers, but not views, as those are not classes, just php files, but You could use render method inside one view to render another view.